# how to check infinity when is division to 0

Tags: javascript, html

I want to check if a result given equals infinity.How can I correctly check it?

```
<input type="text"  name="answer" id="t"  onkeyup="withoutLat(this);withoutCyr(this);checkInfinity(this);" placeholder="Enter data" autofocus>

        function checkInfinity(value)
    {

        var value = calculator.answer.value; 

        if (value == Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY || value == Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)
        {
            alert("Помилка ділення на нуль")
        }
    }
```

Comment: No it doesn't. Only `0/0` results in `NaN` because it's like "one level more indefinite" than other numbers divided by zero. `x/0` will result in `sgn(x) * Infinity` for x!=0, i.e. `5/0` is `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY` and `(-5)/0` is `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`.

Answer (score 3):

```
isFinite(12) //true
isFinite(12/0) //false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = 10 / 0;

if (result === Infinity) {
   alert('Atata!')
}
```

check this out

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity

and jsfidle for you

https://jsfiddle.net/6tzvr1na/